# Installing KiCad 5 and 6 in parallel

Tags: kicad

KiCad 6 has been released, and it makes sense to start using it for new projects.

However I don't want to migrate all my old projects just yet, so I would want to install versions 5.1 and 6 in parallel on the same computer.

Is this possible?

(I'm going to post my own answer for Linux, but Windows/Mac answers would be welcome also!)

Comment: `it makes sense to start using it for new projects.` - a very dangerous thing to say.

Comment: @Andyaka Why? It has worked fine for me so far, and the bugs I've met have been just annoying, not show-stopping.

Answer (score 4):

Below describes how I solved running both versions in parallel.

## General notes for running v5 and v6 in parallel

- For parallel usage, Kicad 6 is compiled from source and when installing, there should not be a conflict necessarily, if at least your current Kicad 5 is situated in /usr/bin/, since Kicad 6 will go to /usr/local/bin
- Use separate project-, footprint- and symbol directories for v5 and v6
- Warning for Kicad Nightly (v6.99): After opening a file with v6.99, it cannot be opened anymore with v6.01, so you are warned when using this version.
- In the footprint library directory settings, you may run into issues with a non-existing variable ${KISYSMOD}, which can be solved by manually editing the $HOME/.config/kicad/6.0/fp-lib-table and replacing the variable with ${KICAD6_FOOTPRINT_DIR}
- For compatibility with v5 I modified the existing kicad.desktop file for v5:

  1. First make a backup of the kicad.png Icon from v5

  ```
  sudo -s -- << EOF
  cp /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/kicad.png /tmp/kicad5.png
  xdg-icon-resource install --novendor --size 128 "/tmp/kicad5.png" kicad5
  EOF
  ```

  2. Then modify the kicad.desktop file:

  ```
  sudo -s -- << EOF
  sed -i "s/Exec=kicad %f/Exec=kicad5 %f/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
  sed -i "s/Icon=kicad/Icon=kicad5/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
  sed -i "s/Name=KiCad/Name=KiCad 5/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
  EOF
  ```

  3. After that add a symbolic link to kicad5:

  ```
  cd /usr/bin/
  sudo ln -s kicad kicad5
  ```

## Compiling Kicad from source

This section below describes in more detail how to build Kicad on linux. Please find the basic instructions here: [dev-docs.kicad.org/en/build/linux/](https://dev-docs.kicad.org/en/build/linux/)

### Dependencies

Most dependencies can be installed via apt package manager. (But depending on the state of your system more packages may need to installed.) The exception for using apt package manager is opencascade (7.6.0). See further below how to install this.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libglew-dev libglm-dev libngspice0-dev swig libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev doxygen doxygen-doc doxygen-gui graphviz
```

Now continue with building opencascade:

Download opencascade 7.6.0 from here: [dev.opencascade.org/release](https://dev.opencascade.org/release) and extract the archive

```
tar xf opencascade-7.6.0.tgz
```

Create a temporary directory for building assets

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Start the cmake wizard

```
cmake ../opencascade-7.6.0
```

Then issue make (Which may take about 1.5 hours or more, depending on the speed of your system)

```
make
sudo make install
```

### Building types

The install location of Kicad v6 can be either in /usr/local or in your profile directory. Both variants are shown below. The build process itself may take about up to two hours.

### Building Kicad to /usr/local

It is safe to build to /usr/local/ There should not be a conflict with an existing Kicad 5 installation. ( which is in /usr/bin ). As a general rule, system maintainers use /usr/bin and applications which you build yourself go to /usr/local/bin

```
mkdir -p $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/
cd !$

# Either a) using git:
git clone git@gitlab.com:kicad/code/kicad.git kicad-6.0.1
cd kicad-6.0.1
git checkout tags/6.0.1
git fetch
# or b) using wget:
wget https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/archive/6.0.1/kicad-6.0.1.tar.bz2
tar xf kicad-6.0.1.tar.bz2
cd kicad-6.0.1


mkdir -p build/release
cd !$
# Start build with (May take several hours):
# If this build will be a local build, set with CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
# default is /usr/local
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
    ../../

make
sudo make install
```

### Building Kicad as local user

It is also possible to build Kicad accessible only as local user. Then the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable needs to point to somewhere in your home profile.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/
cd !$
# create directory containing the final Kicad binary (with bin/, lib/ and share/).
mkdir release

# Either a) using git:
git clone git@gitlab.com:kicad/code/kicad.git kicad-6.0.1
cd kicad-6.0.1
git checkout tags/6.0.1
git fetch
# or b) using wget:
wget https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/archive/6.0.1/kicad-6.0.1.tar.bz2
tar xf kicad-6.0.1.tar.bz2
cd kicad-6.0.1

mkdir -p build/release
cd !$
# Start build with (May take several hours):
# If this build will be a local build, set with CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
# default is /usr/local
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/release \
      ../../

make
make install
```

### Desktop integration

make sure a copy of the existing icon of Kicad 5 is available as described above and use that explicitly as a v5 icon for the system.

In /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop, change kicad in kicad5 for Icon= and Exec=:

```
sudo -s -- << EOF
sed -i "s/Exec=kicad %f/Exec=kicad5 %f/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
sed -i "s/Icon=kicad/Icon=kicad5/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
sed -i "s/Name=KiCad/Name=KiCad 5/g" /usr/share/applications/kicad.desktop
EOF
```

Then add the following symbolic link to kicad5

```
cd /usr/bin/
sudo ln -s kicad kicad5
```

Similarly add the following symbolic link to kicad6

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s kicad kicad6
```

Make an icon for Kicad 6 available:

```
cp $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad-6.0.1/kicad/resources/linux/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/kicad.png $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad-6.0.1/kicad6.png
```

Step below is necessary to make sure that Kicad v6 is invokable as such in your system. For this create a desktop launcher icon to kicad6 (as root user).

```
cd $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad-6.0.1
cat > kicad6-add-menuitem.sh << "eof"
#!/bin/bash
#
# Resolve the location of the installation.
# This includes resolving any symlinks.

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi


if [ ! $# -eq 3 ]; then
  echo "Add application to the unity launcher."
  echo
  echo "    Usage:"
  echo "        $0 APPNAME LOCATION IMAGE"
  echo
  echo "        APPNAME:  Name as it appears in unity launchbar"
  echo "        LOCATION: Location of the binary executable"
  echo "        IMAGE:    Location of the image to show on the launchbar"
  echo
  echo "    For example:"
  echo "        $0 kicad6 /usr/local/bin $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/kicad6.png"
  exit 0
fi

PRG_NAME=$1
BINFILE=$2
IMG=$3

# absolutize dir
PRG_BIN="$(dirname "${BINFILE}")"
oldpwd=`pwd`
cd "${PRG_BIN}"
PRG_BIN=`pwd`
cd "${oldpwd}"

APP="$(basename "${BINFILE}")"
DTFILE="${PRG_NAME}.desktop"

TMP_DIR=`mktemp --directory`

DESKTOP_FILE=$TMP_DIR/${DTFILE}
cat << EOF > ${DESKTOP_FILE}
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=kicad6
Type=Application
Categories=Science;Electronics;
Exec=kicad6 %f
MimeType=application/x-kicad-project;
Name=KiCad 6
GenericName=EDA Suite
Comment=Electronic Design Automation suite
EOF

xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor ${DESKTOP_FILE}
xdg-icon-resource install --novendor --size 128 "${IMG}" ${PRG_NAME}

rm $DESKTOP_FILE
rm -R $TMP_DIR
eof
```

Then install the desktop file and icon by invoking the previous script:

```
sudo ./kicad6-add-menuitem.sh /usr/local/bin $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/kicad6.png
```

When done, the item should appear in your system. (For example in dash in Ubuntu 20.04 under Unity Desktop).

If not refresh menu with:

```
sudo xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode system
```

Or log out and on again, or if not even then, navigate to the following directory:

```
/usr/local/share/applications
```

Drag the Kicad 6 icon to your launcher menu.

## Building Kicad libraries

```
cd $HOME/SOMEWHERE/kicad/
mkdir libraries_v6
git clone git@gitlab.com:kicad/libraries/kicad-symbols.git
cd kicad-symbols
mkdir -p build/release
cd !$
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    ../../
make
sudo make install

cd $HOME/SOMEWHERE/libraries_v6
git clone git@gitlab.com:kicad/libraries/kicad-footprints.git
cd kicad-footprints
mkdir -p build/release
cd !$
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    ../../
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I decided to install KiCad 6 using [the official instructions for Ubuntu](https://www.kicad.org/download/ubuntu/) with `apt-get`, and to install KiCad 5.1.12 from [flatpak](https://www.kicad.org/download/flatpak/).

Flatpak is an alternative software installation scheme that stores all dependencies in a separate directory. That way installing KiCad inside it does not conflict with the system-wide installation under `/usr`. First I had to setup `flatpak`:

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Apparently to downgrade a flatpak package, we must first install the newest version:

```
flatpak install org.kicad.KiCad
```

That will install a bunch of dependency packages also, such as `org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Footprints`. The command `flatpak remote-info --log flathub <package>` can be used to find commit ids for old versions. The following commands downgrade to KiCad 5.1.12:

```
sudo flatpak update --commit=83f184bbbf37c88f2ae48235c9255bb7ab98a28b650508a01b21d379343cf6d7 org.kicad.KiCad
sudo flatpak update --commit=6b7ce398976b7d1ba0c491e968b0d572606b7ac5fc4bbf336f4cb4cd07bd8c6a org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Packages3D
sudo flatpak update --commit=dd75c70703de41fbccd14d6446b1a32ebabe5b919b64667651b84abed65ec800 org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Footprints
sudo flatpak update --commit=18f9a7fd5eb815f4820021c9aafbaa5cce2ec0da4a4e49df46a9c1dc6cff3847 org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Symbols
sudo flatpak update --commit=fbd165ebe3ab480ddd9ac0ddc9bcd3f0b1e306fd4855c9d962ad4cc1258734fd org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Templates
```

I didn't need the locales or the source code packages, so instead of downgrading I removed them:

```
sudo flatpak remove org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Packages3D.Sources
sudo flatpak remove org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Symbols.Sources 
sudo flatpak remove org.kicad.KiCad.Library.Templates.Sources org.kicad.KiCad.Locale
```

Now I can run the system-wide KiCad 6 with `kicad` and the flatpak KiCad 5.1.12 installation with `flatpak run org.kicad.KiCad`

Comment: Thanks for this step by step as it work with my previous linux install. Unfortunately the update commit now return 404, any guess?

Comment: They have probably removed the old versions from flathub. Quite annoying.